# Correct Maven Dependency for Spark API

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, jar

I am wondering if the following dependency declarations are not enough to get access to the following class

`org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction`

**Error at runtime**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/function/PairFunction
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

**Dependencies declared**

```
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
     <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

**I am running the .jar like so:**

```
hadoop jar target/secondarysortspark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar   ~/projects/secondarysortspark/secondarysortspark/src/main/java/com/tom/secondarysortspark/data.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: are you using these classes for tests?

Comment: Not specifically. I have unit tests that run and pass, when I build via mvn package

Answer (score 0):

For your spark version the scala version is not ok. I have the following properties and it works

```
<properties>
        <scala.tools.version>2.10</scala.tools.version>
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.1</spark.version>
    </properties>
```

At least scala 2.10 is required, as for *spark-core_2.10* declare on your spark core dependency(take a look here [spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html))

Comment: Changing the Scala version did not solve the issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The interface PairFunction is in spark-core so your declared dependencies are fine.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/PairFunction.java

The issue is that spark-core is not found on classpath during runtime.

The problem can be solved in a variety of ways depending on your set-up but the easiest in your case is likely to just pass the jar using -libjars option of your hadoop command.

Try something like

```
hadoop jar target/secondarysortspark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ~/projects/secondarysortspark/secondarysortspark/src/main/java/com/tom/secondarysortspark/data.txt -libjars path/to/spark-core.jar
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: Same result. SO strange... hadoop jar target/secondarysortspark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar AppDriver ~/projects/secondarysortspark/secondarysortspark/src/main/java/com/tom/secondarysortspark/data.txt -libjars ~/.m2/repository/com/sparkjava/spark-core/2.5/spark-core-2.5.jar

Comment: The jar you're passing is the (unfortunately named) spark java web framework, the apache spark, i.e. the computing platform jar path should be something like /repository/org/apache/...

Comment: Still same issue...hadoop jar target/secondarysortspark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar AppDriver  ~/projects/secondarysortspark/secondarysortspark/src/main/java/com/tom/secondarysortspark/data.txt -libjars ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/function/PairFunction

Comment: I know this is ages later but in the command you specify spark-core_2.11.jar but in your pom you specify spark-core_2.10. I suggest changing pom version to 2_11.

Additionally are you sure the path you give is correct? The path seems awfully short to me (no spark version for example), I would expect the path to be "~/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11-2.1.0.jar"

Answer (score 0):

We have two options here, do a spark-submit and give the dependency jars in the command as -jars. Or else build a fat jar and do spark submit. Building the fat jar will fix the dependency issue.

Eg. `spark-submit --master  local -- class your_class jarfile_path --jars dependency_jars input_arguements`